# intersection of dplyr select helpers

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to specify a selection of columns of a data.frame to `dplyr`'s `xxxx_at` functions, via the `.vars` argument. But I want to select the intersection of my selections.

Here is an example: a data.frame with names of the form `[abc][abc][abc]`.

```
df <- structure(list(aaa = 1L, baa = 2L, caa = 3L, aba = 4L, bba = 5L, 
    cba = 6L, aca = 7L, bca = 8L, cca = 9L, aab = 10L, bab = 11L, 
    cab = 12L, abb = 13L, bbb = 14L, cbb = 15L, acb = 16L, bcb = 17L, 
    ccb = 18L, aac = 19L, bac = 20L, cac = 21L, abc = 22L, bbc = 23L, 
    cbc = 24L, acc = 25L, bcc = 26L, ccc = 27L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))


# names(df)
# [1] "aaa" "baa" "caa" "aba" "bba" "cba" "aca" "bca" "cca" "aab" "bab" "cab" "abb" "bbb" "cbb" "acb" "bcb"
# [18] "ccb" "aac" "bac" "cac" "abc" "bbc" "cbc" "acc" "bcc" "ccc"
```

I want to select, **in one go**, the columns starting with `"a"` **and** ending with `"c"`. In order to use the solution with `mutate_at`, `group_by_at`, `and_so_on_at`, it needs to fit inside a single call to `vars`.

Using several conditions in `vars` takes the union of them and not the intersection.

```
df %>% 
select_at(vars(starts_with("a"), end_with("c"))) %>%
names

# [1] "aaa" "aba" "aca" "aab" "abb" "acb" "aac" "abc" "acc" "bac" "cac" "bbc" "cbc" "bcc" "ccc"
```

I am trying to get:

```
[1] "aac" "abc" "acc"
```

I have a feeling `all_vars` is relevant but I could not figure out how to use it.

PS: I known I can use `select` instead of `select_at` but I am trying to be general. My actual use case is with `mutate_at`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`starts_with` and `ends_with` both evaluate to column positions. So they both return numbers that represent the column indices. If you want to apply both at the same time you want the intersect of the column indices that are returned by both functions. You can do exactly that by calling `intersect` on the return values of `starts_with` and `ends_with`:

```
df %>% 
  select_at(vars(intersect(starts_with("a"), ends_with("c")))) %>%
  names
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grep("^a.*c$", names(df), value = TRUE)

#[1] "aac" "abc" "acc"
```

---

if you insist to use `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
    select_at(vars(matches("^a.*c$"))) %>%
    names

#[1] "aac" "abc" "acc"
```

Comment: Thanks Andre! I do insist on using dplyr -- the point of the question is not to extract the names but to pass the relevant column selection to `xxxx_at`. I was using `names` just to illustrate.